# Find element size after fullscreen mode is on

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I switch fullscreen mode by

```
$("#myCanvas").webkitRequestFullscreen()
```

How can I find size of the canvas **after** fullscreen mode is on?

I tried to listen 'resize' event as well as 'webkitfullscreenchange', but when they are dispatching, the canvas size is not fullscreen yet.

Comment: can you provide a working example? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't think an example will work inside a SO snippet, because it's an iframe, and `webkitRequestFullscreen` doesn't work for elements inside iframes

Comment: maybe it's not a "rule", but why use an external site when SO has built-in snippets?

Comment: @JeremyThille Correct, and it wouldn't work in a jsfiddle either, but if he's going to ask for one he may as well know to ask for the correct thing :)

Comment: **You can still use sites like JSFiddle if you prefer them.** I really don't see why you would derail this topic

Comment: Does it actually resize at all? From a quick test, it seems like the element remains the same when displayed full-screen, it's just in a black border (Though that may have been a mistake in my test) If you're displaying your canvas relative to the screen size then we'll need to see an example to be able to help.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak This is a community.  You suggested something that would have added no value to the question whatsoever.  I assume that's because you didn't know about snippets, so I told you about them.  It's not derailing if it's for the benefit of the community.

Comment: but it is well within the site rules @Pete

Comment: yeah you literally can't post the question without it, it's not a breakable rule

Comment: opinions are one thing "hey use code snippets, they have the benefits of X Y and Z" but saying "do not ever use fiddles because I dont like it" is ridiculous

Comment: *It will nearly always be too localized* does not apply and neither does *Without code that demonstrates the problem, it isn't even a real question* as long as the relevant code is posted.  Those are not even remotely the same thing mate there is nothing wrong with fiddles, they are allowed here whether you like it or not

Comment: **if only an external link is provided** except that can't happen as we already distinguished. What is your beef dude? https://i.imgur.com/kpmkqME.png it's literally in the aforementioned blog post that **you seem to have not read** yet you call me **blindly ignorant**? I'm pretty sure ad hominem attacks are against the site rules

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak you said to add a fiddle above - that would work in the above question without adding more code to the question so all the code needed to reproduce them problem wouldn't be in the question.  All we are saying is ask for a snippet instead of a fiddle, you're the one that has a massive problem with that, not sure why, it's just typing snippet instead of fiddle.  I'm just trying to point out to you why it is best to ask for a snippet.  If you want to be so argumentative, I couldn't care less about it to be honest, I'll just use my close vote and move on as I currently do

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak This is my final comment on the matter (which I'm sure you'll be relieved to know).  I called a link to jsfiddle absolutely worthless because it is, when jsfiddle is not available.  I don't expect any website to last forever, so linking to an external source is effectively the equivalent to not linking to anything.  As for your aggressive responses, well I have to correct you.  YOU are the type of person that gives Stack Overflow a bad name.  When a community member tries to help you maybe you shouldn't take it personally, because it wasn't.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/kpmkqME.png but fiddles do have a place, and they **can** add value if relevant code is included. I get what you're saying I really do, **snippets are superior to fiddles** I agree with you but there is a difference between **Don't use fiddles** and **fiddles are fine but snippets are better here is why**

Answer (score 1):

I would have put this in a comment... but that seems a bit of a mess right now... xD.

If you're going fullscreen then isn't what you want just the actual size of the screen? Would the `window.screen` object work for you? E.G. `window.screen.width` or `window.screen.availWidth`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen

Playing with it in my console for a bit, my *presumption* is that the fullscreenchange event is being fired before the styles recalc and paint events of the change. In chrome, I was able to get the correct size reported from placing my code inside a double requestAnimationFrame call (thus deferring the code to the next frame).

so your code might look like...

```js
document.onwebkitfullscreenchange = ((evt) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      //code you need to calculate the size of the element here
      console.log(document.querySelector('.container').getBoundingClientRect().width);
    });
  });
});
```

That is true of chrome 68 on desktop at the very least. YMMV.

Comment: Full-screening the entire window and a single element can have different effects, though this may be what they're after, the question isn't super clear.